# Have Woocommerce show product price if id, when not logged in

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have some code that is **blocking the price from being shown on all products, if the user is not logged in**.. this is what I want.

My issue is that I have **1 product that is free, and I need the price to show if the user is not logged in**. only on this single product...

Can someone help me target that single product by id and show price the user is not logged in...

here is my original php snippet in funcions.php which blocks the price from being shown when a user is not logged in

```
// Hide prices on public woocommerce (not logged in)
add_action('after_setup_theme','activate_filter') ; 
function activate_filter(){
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'show_price_logged');
}
function show_price_logged($price){
if(is_user_logged_in()){
return $price;
}
else
{
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item',
'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',        
'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title',
'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
return '<a href="' . get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) .
'">Call for pricing</a>';
}
}
```

Comment: I do have the id for the product, I am just not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the id, you can simply check current product id in your `woocommerce_get_price_html` action:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','activate_filter') ; 
function activate_filter() {
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'show_price_logged');
}

function show_price_logged($price) {
    global $product; // get current product

    if(is_user_logged_in() || $product->id === 8) { // check product id
        return $price;
    } else {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );

        return '<a href="' . get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">Call for pricing</a>';
    }
}
```

But if you need more flexibility you could check product custom field. For example, you could set `is_free` custom field to `true` or any other value of your choice on product edit page and check it's value like this:

```
...
global $product;
$is_free_product = get_post_meta($product->id, 'is_free', true);

if(is_user_logged_in() || $is_free_product) {
    return $price;
} else {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Added $product to the function, and also added a variable with the product ID

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','activate_filter') ; 
function activate_filter(){
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'show_price_if_logged_in', 100, 2
); }


function show_price_if_logged_in( $price, **$product** ){
// Define here your free product ID (here for example ID is 121)
**$free_product_id = 121;**

// Shows the price if customer is logged in or if product is your free product
if( is_user_logged_in() || **$free_product_id == $product->id** )
{
    return $price;
}
else
{
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );

    return '<a href="' . get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">Call for pricing</a>';
}

}
```